# How can I send matrix data to shaders without the Effects11 framework?

Tags: c++, directx11, c

I'm making a Direct3D engine but I'm stuck with this one little problem.

I want to not use effect files but instead use shader files. What can I use to send matrix variables to shaders if I don't use `ID3D11XEffectMatrixVariable`?

Answer (score 2):

To send constant values to shaders without using the effect framework, you [create constant buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476898(v=vs.85).aspx#Shader_Constant_Buffer) and bind them to the pipeline with (for example) [`VSSetConstantBuffers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476491(v=vs.85).aspx).

For example:

```
// You can of course eschew the structure, but this allows you to stuff more data
// into the pipeline with a minimum of fuss; you should generally create constant
// buffers based on what you would update together (per frame versus per object
// state, for example) rather than one-buffer-per-variable.
struct MyConstantBuffer  {
  XMFLOAT4X4 transform;
  // ...optionally more stuff...
};

MyConstantBuffer instance;
instance.transform = someMatrixValue;

// Create buffer description and resource data objects.
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC description = { 0 };
description.ByteWidth = sizeof(MyConstantBuffer);
description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
description.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data = { 0 };
data.pSysMem = &instance;

// Create the buffer and bind it.
ID3D11Buffer * result = nullptr;
device->CreateBuffer(&description, &data, &result);
context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &result);
```

MSDN has [a how-to page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476896(v=vs.85).aspx) as well.